# iOS 10 compatibility to iOS 9 apps

Tags: ios, apple-watch, xcode8

I have launched my iOS app written in swift 2.2 and supports iOS 9 and watch OS 2.2 in app store.  iOS 10 is going to be released tomorrow. How will the app work on iOS 10 environment if any users upgrade to it till the app updates on iOS 10 support are pushed to app store?

I know swift 3 has syntax level changes in methods and a lot. Could anyone please suggest me what the best solution is ?

Comment: Nobody can tell you. If you've used the iOS API 100% correctly your app will work flawlessly. If you've made a mistake your app might crash right after launching. To figure out, run your app on iOS 10. That's what the pre-release versions are for. That has nothing to do with Swift. Your Swift code is compiled, and the Swift library is bundled with your app. Neither of them will change in iOS 10. **TL;DR: Best solution is to download iOS 10 and test your app with it.**

Answer (score 1):

Most of the apps will still work. iOS 10 compatibility has nothing to do with the version of Swift.

The apps are already compiled, when you uploaded them to the AppStore. That's why syntax changes in Swift don't affect old versions of your app.

If your old version uses APIs that are no longer available in iOS 10, it might causes a crash. But if everything worked and was built for iOS 9, you have a really good chance, that the app is still working.

BTW: Didn't you test your app on iOS 10 beta, which was released in June?